# What happened in Argentina in 2001 bank sector? did the banks closed? all or some?

Tags: stocks, banking, bankruptcy, greece, price

What happened in Argentina in 2001 bank sector? did the banks closed? all or some?  i am trying to figure out whats the possible scenario to greek banks if greece goes out of euro and into drahma and declares bankruptcy? What happened in argentina in 2001? did the banks there closed? did the banks trading on the argentinian stock exchange stopped trading? Where i can find historical prices of banks trading on the argentinian stock exchange especially for years 1998 till 2012? to see the reaction the years from 1998 till 2012 had on stock prices of big banks in argentina and hopefully related it to greek banks now

Comment: Here is a documentary on Argentina after the crisis when people could not withdrawal their money from their bank accounts: (http://www.pbs.org/wnet/wideangle/episodes/the-empty-atm/full-episode/670/).  Here is a blog by an Argentinian who lived through the crisis.  He frequently writes about how to survive a currency crisis (ferfal.blogspot.com).

Answer (score 1):

One place you might consider looking for answers is in [case studies from Harvard Business School](http://www.hbs.edu/global/research/latinamerica/archives/).  When I was working an MBA, we studied the default of Argentina as part of our economics coursework.

Other sources for your consideration might include:

- Back issues of The Economist (magazine)
- Archives of The Wall Street Journal
- The World Bank
- The IMF